# In WPF, how do I update the primary UI in a user control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, dispatcher

I have a problem.I want to update the main UI in a user control.I tried so many times, but i didn't make it.The test is divided into  two categories as follows:

Class 1:

I first assigned the main window control (tbInfo, TextBlock type) directly, unsuccessfully. So I created a textBlockUpdate class (implementing the property change notification interface) and  bind its properties (TextMessage) to the Text property of tbInfo，unsuccessfully. Then I used the content control,also unsuccessfully.The code as follows:

```
     //Feature code in user control.
 info = string.Format("Adding file{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName));
         if (_dataObject.MainWindow != null)
         {
                    _dataObject.MainWindow.ShowInfo(info);
         }


//Feature code in main window.
 public void ShowInfo(string info)
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            //tbInfo.Text = info;
            //  textBlockUpdate.TextMessage = info;
            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = info;
            tbInfoContainer.Content = textBlock;
        }
        else
        {
            Action<string> showInfoDel = (str) =>
            {
                //  tbInfo.Text = info;
                //textBlockUpdate.TextMessage = info;
                TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
                textBlock.Text = info;
                tbInfoContainer.Content = textBlock;
            };
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(showInfoDel, info);
        }
    }
```

Class 2:
I put the code in the user control into a thread, or did it not succeed.I tried three times, but I never succeeded.

1.

```
 new Thread(()=>{
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>{
                //Add the feature code above here
            }));
        }).Start();
```

2.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
              //Add the feature code above here
        }));
```

3.

```
 Task task = new Task(()=> { 
   //Add the feature code above here
      });
                    task.Start();
                    task.Wait();
```

So, can anyone tell me How to do to make it work?

Comment: You need none of Dispatcher, Thread and Task. If your UserControl is supposed to update its parent element (e.g. a Window), make it expose a property that it can change. In the parent view, bind to that property.

Comment: If you use data binding your UI will update just fine. Forget about the Dispatcher, go back to basics.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how it is done. Also setting the properties of a class is not called binding. It's a simple assignment.

A [`Binding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding?view=netframework-4.8) connects two or more ([`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=netframework-4.8)) properties (target and source) and updates them automatically, when one of the two changes.
To allow the binding to detect property changes, you have to implement the participating properties either as `DependencyProperty` (mandatory for binding target - preferable on controls) or let them raise the [`INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netframework-4.8#examples) event on property changes.

1. Create the data and binding source

   **MainWindow.xaml**

   ```
   partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
     public static readonly DependencyProperty InfoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "Info",
       typeof(string),
       typeof(MainWindow),
       new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

     public string Info
     {
       get => (string) GetValue(MainWindow.InfoProperty);
       set => SetValue(MainWindow.InfoProperty, value);
     }

     // Update the TextBlock via data binding
     public void ShowInfo(string info)
     {
       this.Info = info;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create the UI an set up the data binding

   **MainWindow.xaml**

   ```
   <Window>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow}, 
                               Path=Info}" />
   </Window>
   ```

### See Microsoft Docs:

[Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview)

[How to: Implement a Dependency Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property)

Comment: I tried your method, but it  didn't work.Maybe I didn't make it clear.I want to achieve such an goal. When I add more than one file at a time to the database, let the UI tell me what file I'm adding. But if I don't use multithreaded programming, I can only add files, not  diplay the UI before adding files. I suspect this may be because the display operation belongs to the UI thread, and in WPF, when the UI operation is in the same method as the database operation, the UI thread is blocked until the database operation is complete. So I'll never   achieve my goals in WPF again?Yes?

Comment: The code is as follows:
 //The following statement performs the UI display of the main window that is data bound（statement1）
                        if (_dataObject.MainWindow != null)
                        {
                            _dataObject.MainWindow.ShowInfo(info);

                        }
                        //The following statement performs a series of database operations（statement2）
                        accessObj.AddFile(_dataObject.Path, fileInfo, fileContent);

Comment: They're in a foreach statement. they loop to add files to the database and tell me what files are being added, but they will only add database files first, and when all file additions are complete, they will eventually display information in the UI at once. So, isn't the setting on thread safety in WPF determined that I'll never be able to achieve my goal? Or, can I only add one file at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.Just change to the following method.

```
 //Call the render thread update UI from the current thread
                    int i = 1;
                    while (i < 10)
                    {
                        if (_dataObject.MainWindow != null)
                        {
                            _dataObject.MainWindow.ShowInfo(info);
                        }
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
                       // Thread.Sleep(100);
                        i++;
                    }
                    //this is a time-consuming process.
                    accessObj.AddFile(_dataObject.Path, fileInfo, fileContent);
                    //Call the render thread update UI from the current thread
                    int j = 1;
                    while (j < 10)
                    {
                        if (j == 1) {
                            _dataObject.AttachFiles.Add(fileInfo);
                        }
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
                        //Thread.Sleep(100);
                        j++;
                    }
```